# How to enable Hybrid Experience in Dynamics 365 V9.0 on premise

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

How to enable Hybrid Experience in Dynamics 365 V9.0 on premise? Currently, I don't have any option to enable the hybrid experience from System->Administration->System Settings.

[image]

As shown above there is no option on "Enable Embedding of certain legacy dialogs in Unified Interface browser client".

If it's not possible, is there any way to make the result from "Advanced Find" open in UCI Form?

Answer (score 0):

We have latest on-prem (9.0.16.7) and also couldn't find this setting. Most probably it will be released in 9.1 for on-prem. I wouldn't expect it earlier then autumn.